# спецификаторы inline __inline __forceinline

Tags: c++

Есть ли отличия в скорости работы кода, если например использовать спецификатор в методе класса?

Comment: В стандарте C++ определен лишь один спецификатор inline. Никакого отличия в скорости работы нет, так как все это делает один и тот же компилятор.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть, иногда.

`inline` не имеет никакого отношения к встраиванию функций, все компиляторы ее игнорируют. По этому единственное практическое применение `inline` - это использовать ее для функций, определенных в заголовочных файлах:

```
// header.hpp
inline void f() {
    // несколько экранов кода 
}
```

Такая функция `f` возможно никогда не будет заинлайнена, но без `inline` ее нельзя разместить в заголовочном файле.

`__inline`, `__forceinline`, и другие расширения компилятора уже могут как-то влиять на то, будет функция заинлайнена или нет.
Однако **в общем случае встраивание функции не приводит к увеличению производительности**. После встраивания функции, производительность может как увеличиться (убрали вызов функции), так и уменьшиться - цикл может стать большим, и перестанут работать предсказания в процессоре (prefetch и т.п.).

По этому `__inline` и `__forceinline` следует применять совместно с бенчмарками, использованием профилировщика, и просмотром сгенерированного ассемблерного кода. Использование этих ключевых слов вслепую не дает никакого эффекта.

Comment: Даже если мне нужно что-то быстро подсчитать? Например вычислить вручную "нормаль вектора" - что я поставлю спецификатор, что не поставлю толку нет?

Comment: Я понял спасибо за информацию.