# Как использовать inline в c++?

Tags: c++

Есть класс на c++ в формате .hpp

```
class  TestBoxC
{
    public:
    TestBoxC (const std::string& testinfo);
    std::string getINFO() const;
    protected:
        std::string _ testinfo;
};

inline std::string TestBoxC:: getINFO() const
{
    return _testinfo;
}
```

В main объявляю, но не работает

```
    TestBoxC *info;
    info-> getINFO();
```

Как можно работать в данном случае с inline ?

Comment: Вы используете inline правильно. Ошибка в чем-то другом. Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: TestBoxC *info; - не создаёт класс, надо оператор NEW

Comment: @Chorkov Компилирую как написано , выдает ошибку - - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1f).Ругается на return _testinfo

Comment: `info` - неинициализированный указатель. Зачем вам вообще указатель, можно просто `TextBoxC info; info.getINFO();`.

Answer (score -2):

Думаю, вы имели ввиду это:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TestBoxC
{
public:
    TestBoxC(const string& lStr);
    inline string getInfo() const;
protected:
    string m_str;
};

TestBoxC::TestBoxC(const string& lStr) : m_str(lStr) {}
inline string TestBoxC::getInfo() const
{
    return m_str;
}

int main() {
    string mystr = "hello world!";
    TestBoxC* info = new TestBoxC(mystr);
    cout << info->getInfo() << endl;
    delete info;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Можно поподробней, что вам не понятно в `inline`?

**`inline` - это ключевое слово в C++ которое указывает компилятору "вставить" код без вызова функции/метода.**

Это может помочь оптимизировать программу (Хоть и на очень маленькое количество времени). Несмотря на указание, компилятор имеет право отказаться от вашего предложения вставки кода и не делать этого, поскольку если код будет слишком большим - это замедлит программу.

Ещё в C++ есть `__forceinline` - ключевое слово, которое "принуждает" компилятор  вставить код функции/метода. Это может либо оптимизировать программу, либо наоборот.  Если код будет слишком большим - это, скорее всего, замедлит программу. Кстати, вроде как, даже от `__forceinline` компилятор может отказаться, если в коде будет try/catch блок.

Дополнительно: [Кляц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480846/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-inline-inline-forceinline)

Comment: `inline - это ключевое слово в C++ которое указывает компилятору "вставить" код без вызова функции/метода` Но по вашей кляц-ссылке написано ровно противоположное: `inline не имеет никакого отношения к встраиванию функций, все компиляторы ее игнорируют`...